# How to add HTML on top of the list of post_type on page admin?

Tags: wordpress

It is possible to add HTML on top of the list of `post_type` on page admin?

Or a MacGyver to do this, e.g. jQuery?

My goal is to do add navigation of custom post_type.

[image]

Comment: Why not add your html using jQuery and do so after `jQuery('.wp-header-end')`

Comment: So this is Mc MacGyver, but exist another way?

Comment: You might be able to find an action / filter but I can't see any in the code